# Low image capture performance Nexus5 with OpenCV-Manager on Android

Tags: android, c++, opencv, nexus-5

I am trying to test the image capture performance using camera api 2 and opencv manager on different devices. I am using the samples included in the repository, Tutorial 1 Camera Preview in especial.

I have tested the sample using a Nexus 4 device, and it is capturing at 30 fps with a big resolution. However, with the Nexus 5 (theoretically more powerful), the performance decreases to 15 fps, and I don't know why.

I have seen similar questions like this: [Extreme camera lag on Nexus 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131900/extreme-camera-lag-on-nexus-4) but nothing is working since now.

Also, the second answer of the previous question suggests to deactivate ZSL (Zero Shutter Lag) feature, but I have not clue on how to do this or even if it could be related.

Any suggestion?